# .NET 7 Blazor - ASP.NET Core Identity Using MongoDB & Social Logins

Tags: asp.net, .net, mongodb, blazor, asp.net-identity

I have recently developed a Blazor application which I am trying to add authentication to. The application uses a few Mongo databases in a single Docker container for all of its CRUD operations. Although I have read some suggestions about using a relational database for my Identity accounts, I would like to continue to use MongoDB for a handful of reasons:

- The roadmap for the application will always be simple regarding user data; I only need to store a few fields per user.
- I plan on only using social logins (Google, Twitter, etc) so I do not need to manage account registrations & logistics.
- I can keep the user database in the same Mongo Docker container with the rest of the app's data.

I am having issues connecting my app's Identity system to a Mongo database. The default Identity code looks like, which points to a SQL Server database:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
});

var app = builder.Build();
```

I would like to point it to MongoDB instead of SQL Server. I have spent the past few days researching Identity in general, as well as looking into (outdated) guides about using it with MongoDB. Some of the guides work alongside AspNetCore.Identity packages, others replace it completely, and I am still struggling to understand which pieces I need in order to use MongoDB for my social logins.

To put simply - how can I modify my Program.cs code to have Identity handle Google sign ups/ins, and store some additional app user data in a Mongo database?